# Question about the behavior of the fortran function MATMUL()

Tags: matrix, fortran

I am a newbie in fortran and i have to multiply matrices of different shapes with MATMUL() and the result is not what i expected...

Here is my fortran code:

```
  integer, dimension(3,2) :: a
  integer, dimension(2,2) :: b
  integer :: i, j

  a = reshape((/ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 /), shape(a))

  b = MATMUL(a,TRANSPOSE(a))

  do j = 1, 2
     do i = 1, 2
        print*, b(i, j)
     end do
  end do
```

I expected this matrix as a result:

b = 
| 3 3 | , a 2x2 matrix 
| 3 3 |

Instead, i got this error message:

matmlt.f90(9): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [B]
      b = MATMUL(a,TRANSPOSE(a))
------^

To make this code work properly i had to switch the MATMUL arguments like this:

b = MATMUL(TRANSPOSE(a), a)

And this way, i obtain what i was expecting at the beginning. But this is not intuitive.

On paper,

a = 
| 1 1 1 |
| 1 1 1 |

transpose(a) = 
| 1 1 |
| 1 1 |
| 1 1 |

a x transpose(a) = 
| 3 3 |
| 3 3 |

and

transpose(a) x a = 
| 2 2 2 |
| 2 2 2 |
| 2 2 2 |

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: A is a 3x2 matrix. Transpose(A) is therefore a 2x3 matrix. Thus A * Transpose( A ) is a 3x3 matrix, which is incompatible with the 2x2 matrix that you have for B. I would put this as an answer but I can't work out why you think b should be 2x2, rather than the correct 3x3 . Could you edit your question to explain why you think this a bit more clearly?

Comment: Looking at it again you seem to have everything transposed A has 3 rows and 2 columns, that is what (3,2) means. Why do you think it is the other way around?

Comment: a (3 columns, 2 rows) matrix with a (2 columns, 3 rows)  matrix will gives a (2 columns, 2 rows) matrix after multiplication

Comment: Fortran is a column-major language.  a(3,2) is a matrix with 3 rows and 2 columns.  So, when you do `matmul(a, transpose(a)`, you are doing the matrix multiplication of a 3x2 by 2x3  matrices with a 3x3 result.

Comment: That Fortran is *column-major* is something of a red herring - an array declared `dimension(3,4)` has 3 rows and 4 columns, as it would in a *row-major* language with a similar syntax.  The layout of arrays in memory (which is what the *major* bit is referring to) does not affect the semantics of array indexing exposed to the programmer.

Comment: @GuyRoy Sorry, but that is not how matrix multiplication works - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: Incidentally, to set every element of a matrix `a` to `1` you can simply write `a = 1`, all the fiddling round with `reshape` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

your matrix definition for the variable

```
     integer, dimension(3,2) :: a
```

means, that you have 3 rows and 2 cols (different ofyour assumption). Subsequently

a= 
|11|
|11|
|11|

and

transpose(a) = 
|111|
|111|

matmul(a,transpose(a)) = 
|2 2 2|
|2 2 2|
|2 2 2|

so your variable b should defined like

```
 integer, dimension (3,3) :: b
```

instead of

```
 integer, dimension (2,2) :: b
```

what is the reason of the

matmlt.f90(9): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform. [B] b = MATMUL(a,TRANSPOSE(a)) ------^

Error

Comment: i was trying to interface C with fortran and because C is row-major and Fortran is column-major, i thought initially that to declare a matrix in fortran, we had to switch the number of rows and columns like this:

C: A[3][2]
Fortran: A(2,3)
From your comments, it should be declared A(3,2) as we do normally.

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: You are right, fortran is column major, but this term describes how the elements of an array are contiguous in memory.

Comment: And i understand that a 2D array pointer declared in C in 1 dimension with malloc(m x n x sizeof()), passed to a fortran subroutine will be automatically transposed because of the way they are stored in memory (row-major (C) to column-major(Fortran)). So in the fortran subroutine, before any manipulation of the matrix, it would be recommanded to (un)transpose the matrix before any processing and before returning the result to the calling c fonction, another transposition would be necessary. Am i right by saying that?

Comment: Hey, from the point of view of memory behaviour you are right. For further reading I could suggest https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/istc/html/language.html.

Comment: Interesting reading. I could modify the way my c array is stored in memory (from row-major to column-major) to emulate the fortran behavior but i think it is not the way to go. I prefer to add a flag to the fortran subroutine indicating if it needs to transpose the array argument or not. By doing that, if this fortran subroutine is called by a c function, the argument flag will be switched to YES (for transposition) and NO if the calling function is in fortran.